# create subdomain programmatically in PHP

Tags: php

I am on shared hosting and on a add on domain.

I need to create subdomain for each user of my website like if the username is jeff then he should have a url jeff.mydomain.com.

How can I create it programmatically using PHP?

Comment: Wow! What about your OS, do you have `bind` installed, do you have access to it and can modify the zones? What web server are you using? Do you have write access to the configuration? ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's two parts to this. Firstly you'll need to setup a [wildcard dns entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record).

Once you've got that setup you should have all your requests pointed back to a single domain. From there you can then use php to figure out which domain you're currently on:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base = 'mydomain.com';
$user = substr($domain, 0, -(strlen($base)+1));// the user part of the domain
if(!empty($user)) {
  $user = sanatiseUser($user);
  require_once $user.'.php';
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `explode( ".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] )` over `substr`. That would allow for better handling of cases where the domain doesn't match the expected (which can happen).

Comment: When i am creating wildcard DNS entry can i make it point to a particular folder under the domain or should it be pointed to the root of the site only

Comment: @Prady The wildcard will point to a server, not a specific directory. You can either configure your web server to point specific hosts at another directory, or you could allow a php script (acting as a controller) to handle all requests and determine how they should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set apache to listen for all domains coming into a specific IP.

You then need to setup a wildcard DNS entry to point `*.domain.com` to that IP.

Then inside your app, use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to determine which user to load.